# Using custom connector's components in same connector's flow

Tags: maven, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

**Problem Description**

I have developed a custom Mulesoft connector using AnypointStudio and following all guidelines on how to do it. However, I am struggling on writing MUnit functional tests for that connector or involving some example flows. The issue is the connector project cannot "import itself", meaning components that I developed for people importing my connector (via Maven for example) are not available for me in my src/main/mule (Flows) location on the Mule Palette.

**Question**

Is there a way to import components from my connector inside the connector itself so that it can use them for example flow? If not, is the right approach here to make new separate project which will import my connector and then have all my tests there?

Answer (score 1):

Test cases for Mule 4 connectors can be done as described at the documentation, using JUnit and Java test cases: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/testing-writing-your-first-test-case

Maven knows how to handle the dependencies for tests so that should not be a problem.

If you want to also integrate MUnit tests you can take a peek at how other connectors do it. You can inspect the open source connectors.

Examples:

- File Connector: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-file-connector/
- HTTP Connector: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-http-connector/

Comment: I was wondering how are these flows in the munit directory created? You cannot reference component from your own connector. So do they create new project -> import the connector -> create flows -> after they're done, move them back to the connector's project?

Comment: Or you can create them by hand.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. My operations can not be imported into the test cases successfully, even tho I exactly followed above test documentation. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't get direct dependencies for rootArtifact: 'com.mycompany:my-connector:mule-extension:0.0.1'`

Comment: Update: one of my dependencies had the wrong scope. After including it into the test scope the import now works as expected